# MySQL Query to split out Delimited String values to Separate Columns

Tags: mysql, sql, stored-procedures

As part of a migration task I need to split out values in an asterisk-delimited string to separate columns. For example, given this string:

```
Case Western Reserve University* University of Kansasi*Middle East Tech
```

I want to return:

| Uni1 | Uni2 | Uni3 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Case Western Reserve University | University of Kansasi | Middle East Tech |

There can be any number of delimited values in the string, so the query needs to be dynamic.

The approach I am working on is using a stored procedure to loop through the string to effectively recreate this:

```
SET @test = "Case Western Reserve University* University of Kansasi* Middle East Technical University";


SELECT SPLIT_STR (@test, '*',3) as third, SPLIT_STR (@test, '*',2) as second;
```

This is what I have so far. It's a work in progress. It loops through the delimited values and uses a function (SPLIT_STR) to pull out the value, but returns the values in one table cell. I've not been able to add 'as val1' to @rval, hence it not splitting into separate columns.

```
DELIMITER //

CREATE PROCEDURE SplitValuesIntoColumns ( delim_str VARCHAR(1000) )

BEGIN

   DECLARE i INT;
  
   SET i = 0;
  
   WHILE (i <= 2) DO
    SET i = i + 1;
        SET @rval =  concat(@rval,SPLIT_STR (delim_str, '*', 1));  
   END WHILE;
   
   SELECT @rval;


END; //

DELIMITER ;
```

Any help appreciated. This seems long winded, so if there's a better way to achieve this, please chime in.

Answer (score 0):

`SUBSTRING_INDEX(SUBSTRING_INDEX(column, '*', xxx), '*', -1)` extracts substring number `xxx`:

```sql
SET @test = "Case Western Reserve University* University of Kansasi* Middle East Technical University";

SELECT SUBSTRING_INDEX(SUBSTRING_INDEX(@test, '*', 1), '*', -1) first,
       SUBSTRING_INDEX(SUBSTRING_INDEX(@test, '*', 2), '*', -1) second,
       SUBSTRING_INDEX(SUBSTRING_INDEX(@test, '*', 3), '*', -1) third;
```

If entered substring number is over the substrings amount then some last substrings returned will be the same.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but the solution needs to be dynamic. There could be one value in the delimited string or ten.. Hence the loop.

Comment: @user15409152 What is **precise** MySQL version? If 8+ then use recursive CTE and generate according numbers table. In 5+ generate it statically in subquery. Accordingly use `ON number <= LENGTH(text) - LENGTH(REPLACE(text, '*', '') + 1)`